# R search subset string from data.table column for Capitalized words

Tags: r, string, datatable, subset, extract

I have a data.table with a "message" column.
I need to extract those messages with following pattern in it

"THISIsNotImportant: **THIS_IS_IMPORTANT** Rest of the Message"

how do i extract the Messages in this pattern and store the segment in bolds into a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(c2 = str_extract(c1, '(?<=:\\s)[A-Z_]+\\b'))
                                                           c1                  c2
1   THISIsNotImportant: THIS_IS_IMPORTANT Rest of the Message   THIS_IS_IMPORTANT
2 THISIsNotImportant: THIS_IS_UNIMPORTANT Rest of the Message THIS_IS_UNIMPORTANT
```

Data used:

```
df
                                                           c1
1   THISIsNotImportant: THIS_IS_IMPORTANT Rest of the Message
2 THISIsNotImportant: THIS_IS_UNIMPORTANT Rest of the Message
```

Comment: I am still facing a difficulty in some rows, where there are multiple whitespaces after ```:```   Does ```\\s``` reads only one whitespace ?

Comment: @Ram yes, you can try: something like this: df %>% mutate(c2 = str_extract(c1, '(?<=:\\s{1,100})[A-Z_]+\\b')). It means any spaces between 1 and 100

Answer (score 1):

```
str_extract(s, '\\b[A-Z_]+\\b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub` in base R :

```
x <- "THISIsNotImportant: THIS_IS_IMPORTANT Rest of the Message"
sub('.*:\\s([A-Z_]+).*', '\\1', x)
#[1] "THIS_IS_IMPORTANT"
```

To add this as a new column in `data.table` for all the rows, you can do :

```
library(data.table)
dt[, imp_message := sub('.*:\\s([A-Z_]+).*', '\\1', message)]
```